# Animation from the 2000s about characters with special stones/orbs that give them power. One was a boy with a sword, and another was a talking dog

Tags: story-identification, animation

When I was young I used to watch an animation on TV somewhere between 2000 and 2005 and I think it was something like post-apocalyptic setting/isekai mix but can't remember its name. What I remember is:

- Each main character had some kind of special stone/orb that gave them some kind of power.
- One of the characters was a boy with a sword/katana, another one was a talking dog and the stone/orb was in its tooth. There was a military guy with a knife, a woman, and a guy with spiky hair.
- The guy with spiky hair found his power towards the end and started throwing dice/cards.
- In the end everyone returned back to their world; the boy was happy, the dog no longer talked, etc and they no longer had powers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This might be *[Shin Hakkenden](https://myanimelist.net/anime/1823/Shin_Hakkenden)* (1999).

> Based on the long cherished, classic Japanese novel Nanso Satomi Hakkenden by Bakin Kyokutei Takizawa (1767), a modified version of it was made into animation.
>
> Taking place in the future, during this time wars were occuring in heaven, mostly for possession between the eight moons created by the savior Fuse that surrounded God's land. When the war ended, there was only one ruling family - that of the Oowaris, and the remaining son gained control of all the moons of heaven, except for one. Meiten, the moon of the pope, where people refrained from war and were therefore out of its terms.
>
> **Eight people. Each from one of the eight moons. Each possessing one of the jewels - the elements that compose Earth.** They are those who are destined to become saviors of humanity. All of them have sacrificed for these jewels, and are determined to complete their duty to Queen Fuse who entrusted these to them. When the mad emperor Kai threatens to revive a ghost who wants to prevent the restoration of Earth, these eight must battle using the powers given by their jewels in order to create Earth and defeat those who want to prevent it.
>
> So they all go to Kusanagi, the ship in the center of God's land. They must gather the jewels in the key called Yatsufusa at Kusanagi's center, in order to create Earth.

There are eight main characters, each of whom possesses a jewel. The lead character, [Kou Yagami](https://myanimelist.net/character/12330/Kou_Yagami), wields a sword with a jewel in it, and there's a talking dog, named [Chuji](https://myanimelist.net/character/12333/Chuji), with a jewel on its left canine tooth. [Jinrai](https://myanimelist.net/character/13200/Jinrai) has spiky hair, and [Gyo](https://myanimelist.net/character/12331/Gyo) seems pretty handy with munitions, so he could be the military guy you mentioned. There are two girls among the main cast, [Noburu](https://myanimelist.net/character/12332/Noburu) and [Ruty](https://myanimelist.net/character/13203/Ruty). And there's a guy with a ponytail called [Tomoka](https://myanimelist.net/character/13201/Tomoka), whose jewel is in a large dice; he's also shown throwing playing cards in the last ten seconds of the video clip below.

Comment: Yes, this it it, thanks for the help. Sorry if my description wasn't very good and made it hard.

Comment: Oh look, remember how everyone praised the realistic black hole imagery in Interstellar? Looks like they just ripped it off of Shin Hakkenden :-))